# Cannot access the Hive tables through JDBC-in R

Tags: r, hadoop, jdbc, hive

I am trying to fetch records of a `hive table` into `R console`.
I have successfully created the connection.  However, when I try to access the `hive table` `weblogs`, it indicates that the table can't be found.

I have already created the `weblogs` table in `HIVE` and I have granted the permission on this table to the user from which I'm logged in.
I am using `derbydb  metaphore`

```
weblogs <- dbReadTable(conn,"weblogs")
```

> Error in .verify.JDBC.result(r, "Unable to retrieve JDBC result set
>   for ",  :    Unable to retrieve JDBC result set for SELECT * FROM
>   weblogs (Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException
>   [Error 10001]: Line 1:14 Table not found 'weblogs')

Comment: Try using the R library RHive.

Comment: I am able to connect with RJDBC now thanks